# Jquery progress bar: How to activate it on document loading/initiation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Below I have a jquery progress bar (see code). Now currently it loads using a start/stop button function. I want it to load automatically first thing before all the other elements of my website loads, since it is a progress bar after all. I want it to start the moment the web page starts to load and I want it to stop the moment the content of the webpage starts showing. (Just to show progress during that white screen waiting period...)

My code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var pct=0;
var handle=0;
function update(){
    $("#progressbar").reportprogress(++pct);
    if(pct==100){
            clearInterval(handle);
            $("#run").val("start");
            pct=0;
    }
}
jQuery(function($){
    $("#run").click(function(){
            if(this.value=="start"){
                    handle=setInterval("update()",100);
                    this.value="stop";
            }else{
                    clearInterval(handle);
                    this.value="start";
            }
    });
    $("#reset").click(function(){
            pct=0;
            $("#progressbar").reportprogress(0);
    });
});
</script>
```

HTML:

```
<div id="progressbar"></div>
<input type="button" id="run" value="start"></input>
<input type="button" id="reset" value="reset"></input>
```

CSS:

```
#progressbar{
    border:1px solid black;
    width:200px;
    height:20px;
    position:relative;
    color:black;
}
/* color bar */
#progressbar div.progress{
    position:absolute;
    width:0;
    height:100%;
    overflow:hidden;
    background-color:#369;
}
/* text on bar */
#progressbar div.progress .text{
    position:absolute;
    text-align:center;
    color:white;
}
/* text off bar */
#progressbar div.text{
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    text-align:center;
}
```

Would Appreciate any help.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Then you should use

```
$(window).load(function () {

                //write you progress bar function here..

    });
```

Comment: "More than one way to skin a cat": jQuery(function($) { }) does more or less that.  Same as $(function() {}), $(document).ready(function() {}).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but you haven't answered my whole question, how to make it start automatically? Currently it uses a start/stop button. Not sure, but do you include this in the head section or the body section? I tried both and it still loads with the onset of the  first html elements in the webpage.

Comment: @Dave :window.load and document.ready are used for differant puropses and not the same.

Comment: are you having any kind of container to load ur pages ??

Comment: @Kabilan: Are you meaning a div container? Yes, everything is contained in one DIV with id="container". I've been looking everywhere for such a PREloader, but non of them PREloads, they load along with the other content, or they work with images...